# Using ECP SAML with ADFS

Tags: saml, adfs

Is there any workaround to use ECP with ADFS? 
ADFS doesn't support ECP. ADFS uses HTTP based redirection which doesn't make sense in our non-web desktop client.

Answer (score 1):

No - it's not supported.

What version of ADFS?

If 3.0, could you use OAuth? - there is limited support.

Refer : [Securing a Web API with Windows Server 2012 R2 ADFS and Katana](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/07/30/securing-a-web-api-with-windows-server-2012-r2-adfs-and-katana/).

Comment: Well, how do you make use of it if it's not supported with AD FS? Why SAML-driven SSO works then?

Comment: ADFS actually implements SAML Lite - ECP is not part of that. Your other alternative is to use the WS-Fed active profile i.e. WCF that is supported by ADFS. Or write some kind of bridge.

Comment: Well WCF is browser-based same as SAML where ECP allows non-browser authentication. It's so weird market did not adapt ECP, is it because OIDC/OAuth?

Comment: ECP was the committees attempt to define an API interface. It was probably ahead of its time and then REST killed it. REST is a much better fit for mobile.

Comment: WCF is an API interface - no browser involved. In WS-Fed, WCF is use for Windows Forms etc.

Comment: That sounds promising, any blog posts/examples of implementations for WCF I could use?